# NodeJS deploying with webpack to Heroku: Build failed with error code: 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I'm having difficulty deploying a react/webpack app with Heroku that works locally without any issues. When I try deploying it a get a large string of text that ends in "Build failed with error code: 1" and then "error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-wildwood-63128.git'". I'm not really sure where the issue is coming from so I've attached my server.js and package.json, please let me know if I'm missing any information that would be helpful. Not sure if its relevant but usually I work with Linux but lately I've been working on Windows. Thanks

edit: updated package json with engines field as suggested

package.json (updated with engine field)

```
{
  "name": "enerjee-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.2",
    "yarn": "1.7.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Sonam",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build:prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.8",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is up on' + port);
});
```

Error text after adding engines

```
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.x|10.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x|10.x...
remote:        Error: Invalid semantic version "8.x|10.x"
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:  !     Invalid semver requirement
remote:
remote:        Node, Yarn, and npm adhere to semver, the semantic versioning convention
remote:        popularized by GitHub.
remote:
remote:        http://semver.org/
remote:
remote:        However you have specified a version requirement that is not a valid
remote:        semantic version.
remote:
remote:        https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-invalid-semver-requirement
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to vast-wildwood-63128.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/vast-wildwood-63128.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-wildwood-63128.git'
```

Comment: I love how it shows "Some possible problems:", with a link to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version, which says exactly what @zakaria wrote in his answer below.

Comment: yeah i originally just assumed that was a generic error suggestion as all the project I've previously deployed to Heroku didn't require an engines field

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the node version in your package.json, so Heroku knows which node version to run.

e.g.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8.x|10.x"
},
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Read specifying a node.js version section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the link and tried adding the versions in the engine field but unfortunately the build now fails with a different error. I've updated the original question with the new package.json and error